# How to change the theme of my tkinter application in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, themes

I'm trying to change my `Tkinter` theme but when I change `s.theme_use('classic')` to `s.theme_use('calm')` or `s.theme_use('winnative')` nothing changes.

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script") # Create window
window.geometry('550x300') # geo of the window

s=ttk.Style()

list_themes = s.theme_names()
current_theme = s.theme_use()
s.theme_use('classic')
print(list_themes)

def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        print("spain")

# These are the option menus
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
dd_owner.set(owner[0]) # the first value
w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner)
w.grid(row=0, column=1)

#The run button
run_button = Button(window, text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()), bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# These are the titles
l1 = Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You are not using any `ttk` widget, like `ttk.Button` and `ttk.Combobox` (replace `OptionMenu`).

Comment: @acw1668 I though that when you do `s.theme_use('classic')` the theme automatically gets changed for all the widgets?

Comment: Theme applies on `ttk` widgets, but you are not using any `ttk` widgets.

Comment: @acw1668 is there not a possibility to change the whole theme at once?

Comment: Yes as long as you have used `ttk` widgets, but you are not.

Comment: @acw1668 can you give me an example. Show it in code please and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an modified example using `ttk` widgets based on your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random

window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script") # Create window
window.geometry('550x300') # geo of the window

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure("TButton", foreground="red", background="blue")

list_themes = s.theme_names()
current_theme = s.theme_use()
#s.theme_use('classic')
print(list_themes)

def run():
    if dd_owner.get() == "Spain":
        print("spain")

    # choose a theme randomly
    theme = random.choice(list_themes)
    print("theme:", theme)
    s.theme_use(theme)


# These are the option menus
owner = ("Spain", "France", "Germany")
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
dd_owner.set(owner[0]) # the first value
#w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner)
# use ttk.Combobox instead of OptionMenu
w = ttk.Combobox(window, textvariable=dd_owner, values=owner)
w.grid(row=0, column=1)

#The run button
#run_button = Button(window, text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()), bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
# use ttk.Button
run_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Run application {}".format(dd_owner.get()), command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=2)

# These are the titles
l1 = ttk.Label(window, text='Select Owner', width=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

When you click the button, it will change the theme randomly.